# Can't make relationship with phpMyAdmin

Tags: mysql, phpmyadmin, relationship

Whenever i try to make a relationship, i only get an empty pop-up and nothing happens...
How can i solve this?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Relationship issue in the MySql designer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8291915/relationship-issue-in-the-mysql-designer)

Answer (score 3):

I had the same problem.

Fix: [add index to the referenced column](https://stackoverflow.com/a/18701075/2096041)

Go to the table structure, and click Index once. Then you'll see it listed if you select the table's index in the left-hand menu. I had the refresh the whole page. Then go to designer and add relation. I had to refresh the whole page once more before seeing the lines appear.

Answer (score 1):

Make sure you have InnoDB tables as you can not make relations on MyISAM tables.

Comment: Also, the fields you want to make relationships between must both have indexes.